# CCMenuItemImage is not responding when used within CCNode custom class

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I have created a custom class LevelScoreCard:CCNode which have some CCMenuItemImages.

Here are the interface and implementation details

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "cocos2d.h"

@interface LevelScoreCard : CCNode {
    @private CCSprite *levelScoreBackGround;
    @private   CGSize winSize;
}
-(id)initForLevelNo:(int)levelNo withWiningStatus:(BOOL)won;

@end
```

and

```
#import "LevelScoreCard.h"
#import "TestLayer3.h"

@implementation LevelScoreCard

-(id)initForLevelNo:(int)levelNo withWiningStatus:(BOOL)won
{

    if( (self=[super init]) ) {

        winSize=[CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;

        //Adding the BackGround
        levelScoreBackGround=[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"levelScoreBackGround.png"];
        self.contentSize=levelScoreBackGround.contentSize;
        [self addChild:levelScoreBackGround ];

        //Adding the Game Level-Wining Status
        CCSprite *winingStatus;
        if (won) {
            winingStatus=[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"levelCompleted.png"];
        }
        else{
            winingStatus=[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"levelFailed.png"];
            CCSprite *skull=[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"skull.png"];
            skull.position=ccp(0,-self.contentSize.height*0.07);
            [self addChild:skull];
        }
        winingStatus.position=ccp(0,self.contentSize.height*0.32);
        [self addChild:winingStatus];

        CCMenuItem *homeButton = [CCMenuItemImage itemWithNormalImage:@"home1.png"
                                                    selectedImage:@"home1.png"
                                                            block:^(id sender) {
                                                                printf("\nHome button clicked");
                                                            }];

        CCMenuItem *replayButton = [CCMenuItemImage itemWithNormalImage:@"replay.png"
                                                    selectedImage:@"replay.png"
                                                            block:^(id sender) {
                                                                printf("\nReplay button clicked");
                                                         }];
        CCMenuItem *nextButton;
        CCMenu *menu;

        NSDictionary *nextLevelInfo=[self gameInformationForLevel:levelNo+1];

        //Create a menu from the button and center it on the screen
        if (![[nextLevelInfo objectForKey:@"isLocked"] intValue]) {
            nextButton = [CCMenuItemImage itemWithNormalImage:@"next.png"
                                                            selectedImage:@"next.png"
                                                                    block:^(id sender) {

                                                                        printf("\nNext button clicked");
                                                                    }];
            menu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:homeButton, replayButton,nextButton, nil];
            [menu alignItemsHorizontallyWithPadding:60];
        }
        else
        {
            menu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:homeButton, replayButton, nil];
            [menu alignItemsHorizontallyWithPadding:20];
        }

        menu.position = ccp(0,-self.contentSize.height*0.35);

        //Add the menu as a child to this layer
        [self addChild:menu];            
    }
    return self;
}

-(NSDictionary*)gameInformationForLevel:(int)levelNo
{
    //---Retrieving Information About Levels----
    NSMutableDictionary *gameInfo=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"gameInfo"];
    NSString *levelKey=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"level%dInfo",levelNo];

    return [[gameInfo objectForKey:levelKey] copy];
}
@end
```

When i am using this **LevelScoreCard from simple CCLayer which is loaded directly from the IntroLayer,the blocks associated with the MenuItems are working perfectly.**

But when I am using it in another CCLayer ***which is loaded conditionally from a second CCLayer, StartLayer with the following code,MenuItems are not responding***

```
    -(void)loadLevelAfterDelay:(ccTime)dt
    {

        #warning  Game has 4 levels, implement game layer 2,3,4 after fixing the story
        switch (levelSelected) {
            case 1:
            {
                [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[CCTransitionFade transitionWithDuration:0.50 scene:[Level1 scene] ]];
                break;
            }
            case 2:
            {
                [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[CCTransitionFade transitionWithDuration:0.50 scene:[TestLayer2 scene] ]];
                break;
            }
            case 3:
            {

                [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[CCTransitionFade transitionWithDuration:0.50 scene:[Level1 scene] ]];
                break;
            }
            case 4:
            {
                [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[CCTransitionFade transitionWithDuration:0.50 scene:[Level1 scene] ]];
                break;
            }


            default:
                break;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem  was that the previous layer StartLayer:CCLayer had a  SettingsMenu:CCNode which was registered to to the touchDispatcher as

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector].touchDispatcher addTargetedDelegate:self priority:INT_MIN+2 swallowsTouches:YES];
```

This was the culprit to swallow touches before they are delivered to CCMenuItemImages.So ,i learned a great lesson which says never register any CCNode type item which will swallow touch.
It's good habit not to swallow touches while registering with touchDispatcher with the following piece of code

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector].touchDispatcher addTargetedDelegate:self priority:INT_MIN+2 swallowsTouches:NO];
```

Comment: actually, you should overload onExit and deregister there for any touch-registered object. Dont forget to [super onExit].

Comment: Thank you YvesLeBorg for your precious comment.